# Access not granted or expired with Service Account in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to change the signature of a user via a service account and domain wide delegation in a Google Apps Script Webapp. This worked fine with a normal Apps Script. I then changed it to a Webapp and created a GCP Project and linked the Apps Script Project to it.

Now I get the following error `Error: Access not granted or expired. at Service_.getAccessToken`

For switching the App Script Project to the new one I followed [these](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) steps. Then I did this:

- created a new service account and created a key
- updated the secret key and service account email in the source code
- added the service account client ID to the GSuite Admin Console->API Controls->Domain Wide Delegation and the needed Scopes
- Enabled the GMail API in the GCP Project

The only thing which I can not explain is in the GCP->APIs & Services-> Credentials. Because in addition of a OAuth Client for the service account I just created there is another one called `Apps Script` which I can not edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` to the `appscript.json` oauthScopes and redeployed the app.

An authorization popup appeared and after I granted access to it, it worked.

I do not think that the problem was the missing scope but that there was no such authorization step when redeploying after I linked the Webapp to the new GCP project.

Comment: In the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) you shared it's stated that when you switch the GCP project from default to standard, all users who have previously authorized the script must re-authorize.

Comment: yes, but I would assume that this will happen when I first deploy with the new GCP project, but it did not. Also is there another way to re-authorize then changing the appscript.json? Or is the "normal" way to add some nonsense changes to the appscript.json so that the authorization window pops up when deploying?

Comment: Just run a function to trigger auth flow

Comment: ah ok, but using the "lates code" and deployment does not trigger it? That is really strange.