# Access not granted or expired. Service_.getAccessToken Error when i run my Gmail Signature Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am having a really frustrating time trying to get my email signature script to run for new users but its works fine for old user accounts.

when i run the script for UserA@...... it successfully updates their signature and the script completes but When i run the same script for UserB@.... it returns the below error:

> Error: Access not granted or expired. Service_.getAccessToken @
> Service.gs:518

Both User A and B are in the same OU and the same type of users but UserB was created afew months after the script was created.

Can any one help please? Its just not making sense to me.

What I have however noticed is that when delete the service account and create a new service account, It tends to work for a short while and then stops again.

I am only running the script for single users as little as once in a month so i can't imagine its quota related but I wouldn't rule out anything at this point.

```
function go() {  
  var pageToken;
  var page;

  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'domain.com',
      orderBy: 'familyName',
      query: 'email=user@domain.com',
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      projection: 'full',
      // query: "email=user@domain.com"
      // query: 'orgUnitPath=/Mentors'
    });
    if (page.users) {
      page.users.forEach( function (user){
        if (accountsToIgnore.indexOf(user.primaryEmail) == -1) {

        var service = getOAuthService(user.primaryEmail);
        // Pull in the signatire template file contents into this variable 
        var signatureTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("signature").getContent();

          // Set up a userData variable, with some blank defaults as backups  
          var userData = {
            email: user.primaryEmail,
            firstName: user.name.givenName,
            lastName: user.name.familyName,
            jobTitle: "",
            showJobTitle: true,
            workingHours: "",
            directPhone: ""
          };
          if (typeof user.customSchemas !== 'undefined') { // Email sig settings are set
            if (typeof user.customSchemas.Email_signature !== 'undefined') {

              if (typeof user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Show_job_title_in_signature !== 'undefined' && user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Show_job_title_in_signature == false) {
                userData.showJobTitle = false; 
              }

              if (typeof user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Working_Hours_Description !== 'undefined' && user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Working_Hours_Description != "") {
                userData.workingHours = "<br /><br /><i>"+user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Working_Hours_Description+"</i><br />";
              }

            }
          }

          if (user.hasOwnProperty('organizations') && user.organizations[0].hasOwnProperty('title') && typeof user.organizations[0].title !== "undefined" && userData.showJobTitle == true) {
            userData.jobTitle = user.organizations[0].title+"<br />";
          }

          if (user.hasOwnProperty('phones') && Array.isArray(user.phones) && user.phones.length >0) {
            for (var p = 0; p < user.phones.length; p++) {
              if (user.phones[p].customType == "Google Voice") {
              // Depending on where in the world you are, you may need to adjust this formatting for your own needs... This replaces the +44 UK country code with a local "0" and adds a space after the local area code for formatting.
               userData.directPhone = "<br />D: " + user.phones[p].value.replace('+44', '0').replace('1158', '1158 '); 
              }
            }
          }

          // Replace the placeholders as seen in the signature.html file with the actual data from the userData variable set up earlier. 
          var userSig = signatureTemplate
          .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")
          .replace(/{email}/g, userData.email)
          .replace(/{firstName}/g, userData.firstName)
          .replace(/{lastName}/g, userData.lastName)
          .replace(/{jobTitle}/g, userData.jobTitle)
          .replace(/{workingHours}/g, userData.workingHours)
          .replace(/{directNumber}/g, userData.directPhone); 

          var sigAPIUrl = Utilities.formatString('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%s/settings/sendAs/%s',userData.email, userData.email);

          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sigAPIUrl, {
            method: "PUT",
            muteHttpExceptions: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            },
            payload: JSON.stringify({
              'signature': userSig
            })
          });

          if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
            Logger.log('There was an error: ' + response.getContentText());
          } else {
            Logger.log("Signature updated for "+user.primaryEmail);
          }
        }
      }); 

    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}

function getOAuthService(userId) {
  return OAuth2.createService("Signature Setter "+userId)
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setPrivateKey(auth.private_key)
  .setIssuer(auth.client_email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setSubject(userId)
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing');
}
```

Thanks Mike

Comment: function getOAuthService(userId) {
  return OAuth2.createService("Signature Setter "+userId)
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setPrivateKey(auth.private_key)
  .setIssuer(auth.client_email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setSubject(userId)
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing');
}

Comment: Would you please include the (formatted) script in the body of the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Related question: [Access not granted or expired with Service Account in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62637290/1330560)

Comment: @Tedinoz  Thanks for the response, I have now edited question and edited with the script. I have seen a few articles saying the OAuth2 token need to be set to renew automatically but i don't even know how to apply that to my current script as this is all unfamiliar territory for me lol. Thought that might help if it is infact a resolution at all . Thanks

Comment: anyone got a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this issue as no one was able to get back to me.

The solution was to create a new project, replicate/copy all Files, Library and Services and that did the trick. Hope this helps someone out there.

Regards
Mike